# Python recursive function returning Nonetype

Tags: python, recursion

I have a function that recursively searches through a 2d matrix to find a value of 0 and return its position. Here is the code:

```
    def findNextZero(x, y, board):
       if board[x][y] == 0:
          return (x, y)
       else:
           if y == (SIZE-1):
              # if its at the edge of the "board", the 2d matrix
              findNextZero(x+1, 0, board)
           else:
              findNextZero(x, y+1, board)
```

When I print (x,y), the function will print the proper tuple. However, if I try to return it, it says the returned value is None. Why is this occurring?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are *ignoring* the return value of recursive calls. Add `return` statements for those:

```
def findNextZero(x, y, board):
    if board[x][y] == 0:
        return (x, y)
    else:
        if y == (SIZE-1):
            # if its at the edge of the "board", the 2d matrix
            return findNextZero(x+1, 0, board)
        else:
            return findNextZero(x, y+1, board)
```

Without those `return`s, the `findNextZero()` function just ends without returning anything explicitly, resulting in the default return value being returned anyway.